# Plist file editing: How to create an endless level similar to Doodle Jump?

Tags: ios, swift, plist

I am following a RayWenderLich's tutorial on how to create a game similar to Mega Jump found [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/87232/make-game-like-mega-jump-sprite-kit-swift-part-2)

However, rather than making levels I want to create an endless level, but I am not sure how to go about doing it.

I figured that in order to reach that goal, I would have to edit something within plist file.

If someone can please help with this that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why would you have to edit the plist file? I believe you can do it through code.

Comment: @penatheboss How would I go about doing that?

Comment: If you could show what you have so far, I could edit it!

Comment: This is what I have so far https://github.com/SeyiWills/JumpPig2-